# "Unable to Locate DLL" when using opencv to capture video from camera

Tags: c++, opencv, dll

I applied tutorials on the internet for installing opencv 2.9 but I get

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFC6470C0B4 (ntdll.dll) in Project11.exe: 
0xC0000135: Unable to Locate DLL.
```

I tried the below code but have been unable to solve it.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "opencv.hpp"

int main(){
    CvCapture *camera=cvCaptureFromFile("rtsp://192.168.1.19:554/0/1:1/main");
    if (camera==NULL)
    printf("camera is null\n"); 
    else
    printf("camera is not null");

    cvNamedWindow("img");
    while (cvWaitKey(10)!=atoi("q")){
            IplImage *img=cvQueryFrame(camera);
            cvShowImage("img",img);
    }
    cvReleaseCapture(&camera);
}
```

Comment: as the error message says, it's unable to locate the the dll. your includes are strange ! and in you're using opencv.hpp it means that you have to use the c++ opencv api but you're code is in C, I'll definitely recomend the C++ your life will be much more easier

Comment: @Engine I would personally work on your spelling/grammar...

Comment: @Engine Their `#include`s are weird because they're attempting to use individual code files from the sourcecode from the library.

Comment: @cybermonkey he've just edited the question  it was definitly wrong !

Comment: @Engine Eh? I don't understand.

Comment: chekc the history of the question, it was like #include #include #include without mentioning any header files

Comment: @Engine True, but the OP is *still* using *.hpp* files, which are used in the `OpenCV` shared library source-code. The OP is using these files wrongly.

Comment: @Mehmet Why did you unaccept my answer?

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states, the required DLL can't be found by Windows.
This error is most likely caused by the absence of the `OpenCV` DLL; ***it must be placed either***:

- In your `System32` directory (usually `C:\Windows\System 32`)
- In the same directory as your executable
- Appended to your system's `PATH` environment variable

Please see the [OpenCV Installation on Windows](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html) page for more information on the proper installation of the OpenCV libraries.

You're attempting to use the individual files from the `OpenCV` library source-code. Whilst this might work, it is not advisable.

***TL:DR;*** You must find the `opencv_core[version number here]` and place it in one of the locations I mentioned above.

Comment: @Downvoter: Care to comment on ***why*** you downvoted, instead of 'ringing the doorbell and running'? My answer provides a correct answer to their question.

Comment: please do not recommend moving the dlls around, that's horrible. instead, the folder containing the opencv dlls should be appended to the PATH env variable. (yes, i'm one of your downvoters)

Comment: @berak How is that 'horrible'? Any external DLLs should be included in the executable's directory, appended to the PATH environment variable, or (not recommended) put in the `Windows` directory. I edited to reflect that.

Comment: I applied path environment variables issue from tutorials and I referenced it from the visual studio. It still gives error

Comment: @MehmetEminörs Ignore berak. Have you tried copying the OpenCV DLL to the same directory your program is being executed from?

Comment: copying dlls totally defeats the idea of 'shared' libraries. imagine, you have 20 programs using opencv, all with a debug and a release version.

Comment: @berak Obviously 'your way' doesn't work in the OP's scenario.

Comment: Interesting, currently +2/-3.

Comment: after copying opencv_***.dll files into system32 folder and changing the true rtsp address problem is solved

Answer (score -2):

you should copy dll files(C:\opencv\build\x64\vc11\bin) In your System32 directory (usually C:\Windows\System 32)